# Am I using Html.Raw() safely?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an ecommerce gift store where users can fill out a gift-card for their recipient.

In order to fill out the card, I have the users enter text into a multiline textbox.

When I display the gift-card on the final review page, I have to spit out the information with Html.Raw so that Newlines are being displayed properly.  I'm doing this:

```
@(Model.GiftCard.Text != null ? Html.Raw(Model.GiftCard.Text.Replace(char.ConvertFromUtf32(13),"<br />")) : Html.Raw(""))
```

I'm frightened that i'm entering dangerous territory using Html.Raw on values that were user-entered.  However, when I go back to the gift-card entry page, the page breaks when I try to do something like "This is my gift card! (scripttag)alert('test');(/scripttag)"... so I feel like .net will catch any malicious entries during that point.

Am I safe to proceed like this?  It seems that since the gift-card entry page is running validations against malicious code, I should be okay to use HtmlRaw later to display newline html that I'm putting in myself...

(I replaced the actual script tag with this (scripttag) thing above so it will show in stackoverflow)

Comment: I would put a validation on the field limiting the entry to acceptable characters and/or do an html.encode on the value.

Comment: Do you have an example or link that will help me make sure i only allow acceptable characters?  Wouldn't that be in javascript (hence, you can hack around it and post something else anyway?)

Comment: yes it would be javascript. yes possibly that's where the html.encode on the field comes in so characters that could be used for an injection attack are handled. I'll dig around for some JS validation I can post.

Comment: Couldn't you explicitly HtmlEncode the string before doing the replace? Then you'd be perfectly safe using Html.Raw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression in your view model to make sure people only enter A-Za-z0-9 and whatever else you think should use such as :) =] type of stuff. Screening this stuff front end is better than second guessing it on the way out.

Comment: Or make a regex that prevents the usage of < and >

Comment: And anything that your database might convert to < or >, or any string conversions between... You should always disallow all except for specific well defined values rather than prevent specific chars.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a 
    <pre></pre> 
tag instead? This would allow returns to display in HTML without  the need for Html.Raw?